# PyQt5 incorrect label formatting with links

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, pyside2

I have two issues with how PyQt is formatting my QLabels

**Issue 1:**
When hyperlinks are added it displays as if there were no newlines in the string.
For the input text:

```
<a href = "https://www.google.co.uk/">https://www.google.co.uk/</a>    

<a href = "https://www.google.co.uk/">https://www.google.co.uk/</a>    

<a href = "https://www.google.co.uk/">https://www.google.co.uk/</a>
```

It's shown like this without newlines

[image]

**Issue 2:** Sometimes PyQt just doesn't even detect the 'a' tag this happens when the start of string is not a hyperlink but it is then followed by newlines with hyperlinks e.g. this input:

```
test

<a href = "https://www.google.co.uk/">https://www.google.co.uk/</a>    

<a href = "https://www.google.co.uk/">https://www.google.co.uk/</a>    

<a href = "https://www.google.co.uk/">https://www.google.co.uk/</a>
```

As you can see the newlines are properly shown but PyQt has no longer detected the hyperlinks

[image]

Comment: did you try `<br>` instead of new line ?

Comment: better create minimal working code which we could simply copy and run it - and test ideas.

Comment: Looks like a case of garbage in, garbage out. If you want reliable html parsing, use properly formatted html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [text property documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#text-prop) of QLabel:

> The text will be interpreted either as plain text or as rich text, depending on the text format setting; see [setTextFormat()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#textFormat-prop). The default setting is Qt::AutoText; i.e. QLabel will **try** to auto-detect the format of the text set.

The `AutoText` flag can only make a *guess* using simple tag syntax checks (basic tags without arguments, such as `<b>`, or document type declaration headers, like `<html>`).
This is obviously done for performance reasons.

If you are sure that you're always setting rich text content, use the appropriate [`Qt.TextFormat`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#TextFormat-enum) enum:

```
    label.setTextFormat(QtCore.Qt.RichText)
```

Using the HTML-like syntax of rich text will obviously use the same basic concept HTML had since its birth, almost 30 years ago: line breaks between *any* word in the document (text or tag) are **ignored**, as much as multiple spaces are always considered as one.

So, if you want to add line breaks, you have to use the appropriate `<br>` (or `<br/>` for xhtml) tag.

Also remember that Qt rich text engine has a **limited** support, as described in the documentation about the [Supported HTML Subset](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html).